# Spring Roo entity relationships - date formatting

Tags: spring, date, format

I have 2 entities: *Document (number, date,repartizari)* and *Repartizare (document, date)* (repartizare means allocation) with a ONE_TO_MANY relationship, one *Document* may have many *Repartizare*.

The *Document repartizari* field is set of *Repartizare* type and mapped by *Repartizare document* reference field.

The *Document date* field is formatted as SHORT dd/MM/yyyy, but the problem is when i try to create a new *Repartizare* in the *document* field drop-down list the *Document date* appears in long format ([see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJu5E.jpg)).
What do I need to modify so the date will be short format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I edited the `Converter<Document, String> getDocumentToStringConverter()`'s returned result from the `ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean.aj` after pushing it in the java class.